# Image upload size limit in liferay

Tags: image, liferay

I would like to limit the size of image upload that the user can make in liferay without affecting the upload size of other files such as PDF or videos. If I limit by path System Settings -> Infrastructure -> Request upload servlet, liferay limits all file types.

[image]

Comment: Please carry this over to the Liferay community, as it's not programming related (at least not the way this question is asked), thus off-topic here. See [help/on-topic], [ask] or the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Liferay doesn't allow configuring the maximum upload file per file type.

There is a feature request to implement it, see issues:

- https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-102325
- https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-114786

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want can be injected into the Portal by overriding its core services using a [custom service with higher rank](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017889552-Overriding-OSGi-Services).